# Should I return 501/505 HTTP status or 400/404

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

If I have a tomcat server running and make a GET request to a resource that does not exist I would expect a response status of 404 not found.  If however I make a request to the same non existing resource with a method that is not supported such as "nGET" then I get a response with status of 501.  Is  this correct?  I would assume that if the resource does not exist then I would get a 404.

The same question goes for the 505, if I make a request to the Tomcat with an unsupported protocol version to a non existing resource should I expect a 404 or a 505?

Comment: Which code takes precedent and where does it mention this in the spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HTTP 1.1 spec on the 400 class of reponse codes:
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4

> 10.4 Client Error 4xx
>
> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the client seems to have erred...

And also the 500 class of response codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5

> 10.5 Server Error 5xx
>
> Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of performing the request

One status does not mention that it takes precedence over another, it should be a matter of what is the most important status code for you to convey.

Trying a default Apache 2.2 installation (without Tomcat) seems to respond with a 501 Method Not Implemented response when I request a missing resource with an unsupported method, pointing more to a server issue - that would appear to be similar to how Apache+Tomcat behaves.

Conversely a request to an Amazon CloudFront endpoint again with both a missing resource and unsupported method returns a 400 Bad Request response, indicating that is leaning more to conveying a client error.

At the end of the day for situations where you have more than one problem you would do best to have the client solve both.  So long as you return the one correct response code for when there is only one issue, trying to solve multiple issues in a specific order is a matter of taste.  It is useful to note that both the 400 class and 500 class definitions include the phrase:

> User agents SHOULD display any included entity to the user

You can include whatever detailed information in the body of the response you see fit, which in cases where there are multiple issues, means you could include text to describe all the problems with the request.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that those two 500-status codes would take precedence, in some sense, over a 404 not found. I look at 501 and 505 as the server responding to the nature of the HTTP request, before it made any attempt to resolve the request in any meaningful way. Since it would, in effect, say "I'm not answering that request method or HTTP version" before it tried to find the resource that was requested, I would expect either of those 500-errors to occur before receiving a 404.